# Azure (worker role?)- send small file - process - return response file. Why so complicated?

Tags: azure, service

I'm finding a steep learning curve on all this Azure stuff. Yeah if I want to do everything in Azure, then I can architect everything and pull in old logic,...

But, what if I want to just replace the process intensive step?

Can I setup a worker role(web role, service,...?) to just take in a small file or string of text and then process the heck out of stuff and then return me the results file or text? How come this seems so hard to do?

If I can (how?), could I also call this from a local app? (I guess if it was a web service or something I would do a webrequest/response.

Should I wait a year? I feel like 'they' will make things easier to use, and investing all this time to figure out how to use Azure may not be worth it.

Comment: Asking whether to wait on Azure for a year, and asking generically how to do something, is soliciting opinions. Not a good fit for StackOverflow. You may want to edit your question to get rid of the opinionated remarks and replace them with the code or logic you're trying to use, so that others can help you figure out where the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more on the requirements, it's hard to give an exact answer.  My first suggestion would be to not over complicate this.  So let's step back and look at what you've told us so far.

1. You have some text that you want to send to some process to have work done and then return some results.
2. The text could be either a file or string of characters
3. Getting this text to the process may be done via a web request
4. We don't know how the response should be handled, but kind of feels like a request/response flow (i.e. send some data, wait a bit, get a response).

Correct?

In that case, I think you have several options:

1. Create a web site or API that would accept your incoming data, do the work, and eventually return (less ideal).
2. Submit the data directly to a data store of some type (queue, blob, table, etc.)
3. Process the data and store the results.  Processing could be done async via a Worker Role or Web Job.  Store the data someplace you can access it again (table, blob, etc.)

In the end, given the info provided, the problem isn't really an "Azure" problem.  Windows Azure has many components available in the platform. You can pick the ones that suite your needs the best. Having options is a good thing.

Let me ask this - how would you do this if Windows Azure was not in the picture?